# How to manipulate pandas dataframe with multiple IF statements/ conditions?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm relatively new to python and pandas and am trying to determine how do I create a IF statement or any other statement that once initially returns value continues with other IF statement with in given range?

I have tried .between, .loc, and if statements but am still struggling. I have tried to recreate what is happening in my code but cannot replicate it precisely. Any suggestions or ideas around this problem?

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Yrs': [ '2018','2019', '2020', '2021', '2022'], 'Val': [1.50, 1.75, 2.0, 2.25, 2.5] }

data2 = {'F':['2015','2018', '2020'], 'L': ['2019','2022', '2024'], 'Base':['2','5','5'], 
         'O':[20, 40, 60], 'S': [5, 10, 15]}


df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
r = pd.DataFrame()

#use this code to get first value when F <= Yrs
r.loc[(df2['F'] <= df.at[0,'Yrs']), '2018'] = \
(1/pd.to_numeric(df2['Base']))*(pd.to_numeric(df2['S']))* \
(pd.to_numeric(df.at[0, 'Val']))+(pd.to_numeric(df2['Of']))

#use this code to get the rest of the values until L = Yrs  
r.loc[(df2['L'] <= df.at[1,'Yrs']) & (df2['L'] >= df.at[1,'Yrs']),\ 
'2019'] = (pd.to_numeric(r['2018'])-  pd.to_numeric(df2['Of']))* \
pd.to_numeric(df.at[1, 'Val'] / pd.to_numeric(df.at[0, 'Val'])) + \
pd.to_numeric(df2['Of'])
r
```

I expect output to be:(the values may be different but its the pattern I want)

```
     2018    2019    2020    2021    2022
0    7.75    8.375   NaN     NaN     NaN

1    11.0    11.5    12      12.5    13.0

2    NaN     NaN     18      18.75   19.25
```

but i get:

```
     2018    2019    2020    2021    2022

0    7.75    8.375   9.0     9.625   10.25

1    11.0    11.5    12      NaN     NaN

2    16.50   17.25   18      NaN     NaN
```

Comment: what is `df2['Of']`?  `df2['O']` or `df2['F']`?